# Why won't a moderator delete my closed, abandoned question?

Tags: support, questions

Because I was not aware that I could update a question for new requirements, I posted [a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41488450/template-class-to-call-some-named-function-of-other-classes-based-on-their-prese) instead of updating [my original one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41523636/detect-and-select-a-particular-prototype-of-function-in-different-class-structs).

That original question is closed and almost a copy of the new question, so I flagged it and asked for a moderator to delete it. However, my flag was declined. Why won't a moderator delete it?

Comment: I guess because it will have upvoted answers? Hard to tell without the exact question.

Comment: Check this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41523636/detect-and-select-a-particular-prototype-of-function-in-different-class-structs  and I have marked it as almost a copy of  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41488450/template-class-to-call-some-named-function-of-other-classes-based-on-their-prese

Comment: I just expect a moderator to understand my problem that sometimes people simply downvote because they dont read edits i Have made.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both questions this concerns have upvoted and accepted answers. Deleting your question would also mean deleting other apparently useful contributions. That is unlikely to happen at the hands of a moderator.

At "best" one question can be closed as the duplicate of another, if it meets those conditions. But the questions are likely here to stay.

Comment: THE SOLUTION TO THE FIRST QUESTION WHICH I fLAGGED WAS NOT EXACT SO CAN I REMOVE IT AS AN ACCEPTED ANSWER?

Comment: the only upvote it has was mine as I find that useful for me.

Comment: is that a good practice?

Comment: One really good practice is turning off your Caps Lock key. @cool Anyway, I did my part here; I cast a delete vote on that question several days ago, when I first saw it.

Comment: @CoolVirus I may regret this, but you can unaccept and unupvote (if it's been edited) the answer and then self-delete your question. In theory.

Comment: *At "best" one question can be closed as the duplicate of another* - Isn't it possible for dupe questions to be merged? Or does that only work if one of them doesn't have answers?

Answer (score 15):

Here are the responses you have received to your multiple flags on this question:

> declined - We don't delete questions that have received good answers, as it is unfair to the answerers. Use the /contact page to ask for dis-association if the need be. This will save the downvotes

and

> declined - We do not delete questions once they have accrued answers, as the posted solutions may prove helpful to future visitors

and

> declined - I see no reason to delete this answer.

and

> declined - There's no use flagging the same post for the same reason multiple times.

I think multiple moderators explained ourselves pretty clearly here. In general, we don't delete questions at the request of the asker if there are good, upvoted answers to them.

It appears that you are trying to delete this question in an attempt to work yourself out of a question ban, and I can tell you this will not help. As the first moderator indicated in their decline reason, you could possibly contact SE staff to request dissociation of this question from your account, but pure deletion will not do anything to help a question ban.